# Determining whether a base is a Generator in $Z^*_{11}$ as well as differentiating Primitive Root and/or Primitive Element?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cyclic-groups

Given $Z^*_{11}$, specifically looking at the bases $2$ and $3$:

\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline 2^1 \pmod {11}=2 & 3^1 \pmod {11}=3 \\ \hline 2^2 \pmod {11}=4 & 3^2 \pmod {11}=9 \\ \hline 2^3 \pmod {11}=8 & 3^3 \pmod {11}=5 \\ \hline 2^4 \pmod {11}=5 & 3^4 \pmod {11}=4 \\ \hline 2^5 \pmod {11}={10} & 3^5 \pmod {11}=1 \\ \hline 2^6 \pmod {11}=9 & 3^6 \pmod {11}=3 \\ \hline 2^7 \pmod {11}=7 & 3^7 \pmod {11}=9 \\ \hline 2^8 \pmod {11}=3 & 3^8 \pmod {11}=5 \\ \hline 2^9 \pmod {11}=6 & 3^9 \pmod {11}=4 \\ \hline 2^{10} \pmod {11}=1 & 3^{10} \pmod {11}=1 \\ \hline  \end{array}

$ord_{11}(2)=10$ which is equivalent to $φ(11)=10$, so $k$ is the smallest integer
in $2^k \equiv 1 \pmod {11}$.
$ord_{11}(3)=5$, where $5$ is the smallest $k$ 
in $3^k \equiv 1 \pmod {11}$.

I'm fairly certain that $2$ is a generator, however I don't think $3$ is a generator because it doesn't generate every power in $Z^*_{11}$? But I've seen some posts that conflict with this. If $2$ is a generator, is it also a primitive root? I've also seen the term primitive element and wonder if it is synonomous as well?

Comment: g is a primitive root (synonymously, a primitive element) mod n if and only if g is a generator of the multiplicative group of integers modulo n; 2 is, 3 is not (mod 11); mod 7, 3 is, and 2 is not

Comment: What posts conflict with this?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner it turns out that it was my conflict :). I mistakenly took generating a cyclic group as synonymous with generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x$ is a primitive root (synonymously, a primitive element) mod $n$ if and only if

$x$ is a generator of the multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$.

Modulo $11$, $2$ is a primitive root and $3$ is not.

Modulo $7$, on the other hand, $3$ is a primitive root and $2$ is not.

Comment: Is the requirement of a generator of a multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$, that it "generate" ALL of (in this case powers) of the smallest positive, non zero remainders of $n$?

Comment: it must generate all those that are *relatively prime* to $n$ (equivalently, elements of the multiplicative group, which are *invertible* modulo $n$); if $n$ is prime, that means ALL except $0;$ but, for example, modulo $6$, which is not prime, the only invertible elements are $1$ and $5$ -- there's nothing you could multiply by $2$ or $3$ or $4$ to get $1$ modulo $6$

Comment: Not being sarcastic...and by "those" and "elements" are you referring to the smallest positive, non zero remainder system? For example, in $Z^*_{11}={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}$.

Comment: yes, though I don't really care whether you use that remainder system or some other; my point was, for example, $\mathbb Z_6^*$ is only $\{1,5\}$, and has $5$ as a primitive root